# Serializing/deserializing a sqlite database with the Visual Studio Entity Framework & C#

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, version-control, sqlite

I'm using the SQLite.net provider and VS Entity Designer to design and code against a sqlite database. At present, a model sqlite database is checked in to the source tree.

However, this is binary which is inconvenient for use with a revision control system.

I'd like to check in a serialized version using sqlite's .dump, but am not sure what the steps would be to achieve the following:

1. A serialized form of the model database is checked in to the tree.
2. When the solution is opened or updated from the source control system, the SQLite database used by the designer is automatically updated.
3. Changes to the database from the database designer update the serialized version.

Are there a set of custom build steps that would make this relatively seamless?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Where I'm at, I want to be able to just check out a project from subversion and compile it without modification.  That means having the sqlite db available as a binary.

I understand the desire to be able to diff against, but you can get almost as good functionality by making good check-in comments.  Unless the conversion happens at the level of your source control client, having to maintain the .dump will just add friction to your development process, and that's probably the larger concern.

Comment: Thanks Joel, I may end up doing this but am still holding out for a good text solution with low friction. Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

I find it a good practice, if a little cumbersome, to put SQL DDL scripts under source control when database versioning is necessary.  If you have a test dataset, you can import it at the beginning of your build and test runs.